# How to build the seamless bridge between two blockchain platform?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, oracles

How to build the bridge between two different consensus blockchain platform?

use case:

1.we need to ensure visibility of the transaction in both platforms to assure its integrity

2. When a smart contract is established on one platform, that contract can be referred to, transacted and transferred to the other platform easily and securely
3. The bridge should be able to leverage the one platform and other platforms depending upon the transaction type and the TPS requirement. If it requires a faster TPS, then one consensus framework or else normal mining framework of another consensus

Comment: Bancor did that, see [here](https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts/blob/master/solidity/contracts/bancorx/BancorX.sol).

Comment: there are multiple ways of securing a cross-chain transaction, but I'm not sure what you are talking about for point 2, do you mean that you want cross-chain contract calls? so a contract on chain A can call a contract on chain B and get the return result? Or by "transferred to" do you mean you want the contract on chain A itself being able to be transferred to chain B?

Comment: @hellpeach yes, want the contract on chain A itself being able to be transferred to chain B

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of bridge services readily available for Ethereum, obviously the use will depend on your exact use case, but here are a selection of projects for you to review:

- Parity Bridge: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridge
- Ion: https://github.com/clearmatics/ion
- And here is a sample project of having 2 Quorum blockchains implementing a custom exchange bridge: https://github.com/M-Bowe/pons & https://github.com/M-Bowe/pons-frontend

Comment: Is this for between Ethereum and other blockchain platforms (Example such as EOS, Stellar, Tron)?

Comment: Ion is a generic one. Parity Bridge is a sample of how to bridge Ethereum and X.

Comment: Is Parity Bridge satisfy all use cases that I have written in the question?

Comment: AFAIK, it would allow you to do that -- this is the pieces you'd need to be writing imho

Comment: Is that bridge act as a server?

Answer (score 0):

Can you google `sidechain dapp` please and see if this is what you are looking for ?